# How to set field in model that was not defined in Meta class

Tags: python, django

In `django`, how do we set fields that were not defined in `class Meta`?`

I have this model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    password_hash = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    password_salt = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

and this form:

```
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    repeat_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['user_name', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        repeat_password = cleaned_data.get('repeat_password')

        if password is not None and repeat_password is not None:
            if password != repeat_password:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match.")

            password_validate = password_validate = password_validation.validate_password(password)
            if password_validate is not None:
                raise password_validate
```

I only want the user to be able to set `user_name`, `email`, `first_name` and `last_name` fields. In `clean(self)` I check if the entered passwords match and if they are valid.

What I want to do now is to set `password_hash` and `password_salt` of my model `User`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean method in the ModelForm only validates the fields in a form.
It does not set any data to the models. What you are doing in your clean method is that, you are checking whether the posted data is in the required format you intended or expected. You could look more into that here [in the docs..](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

For "setting" fields as you said you may need to override the form save method.
[Here in the docs..](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

> The save() method¶
>
> Every ModelForm also has a save() method. This method creates and saves a database object from the data bound to the form. A subclass of ModelForm can accept an existing model instance as the keyword argument instance; if this is supplied, save() will update that instance.

From what I understand you could do something like this,

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    instance = super(ContactForm, self).save(commit=False)
    instance.password_hash = #...How you want to do your password_hash is here.
    instance.save()
```

If you are looking for manually creating/managing passwords, I think this maybe what you are looking for :

[Setting passwords manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers)

> make_password(password[, salt, hashers])
>
> Creates a hashed password in the format used by this application. It takes one mandatory argument: the password in plain-text. Optionally, you can provide a salt and a hashing algorithm to use, if you don’t want to use the defaults (first entry of PASSWORD_HASHERS setting). Currently supported algorithms are: 'pbkdf2_sha256', 'pbkdf2_sha1', 'bcrypt_sha256' (see Using bcrypt with Django), 'bcrypt', 'sha1', 'md5', 'unsalted_md5' (only for backward compatibility) and 'crypt' if you have the crypt library installed. If the password argument is None, an unusable password is returned (a one that will be never accepted by check_password()).